# Does the browser set the cookies when there's a redirection?

Tags: php, cookies, header

I think I'm making an awkward mistake here but I really fail to find it. I've used browser developer tools and watched each step closely. This is the code and I want the number of visits to get reset after the Restart link is pressed, but it just keeps incrementing:

```
//test.php:
 <?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['visits']) && isset($_GET['restart'])){
    if($_GET['restart']=='true') {
        setcookie('visits',null,time()-24*3600*365,'/');
        unset($_COOKIE['visits']);
        header("Location: test.php");
        exit;
    }
}
if(!isset($_COOKIE['visits'])){
    $visits = 1;
    setcookie('visits',$visits,time()+24*3600*365);
    echo "Welcome To This Website";
}
else{
    $visits = $_COOKIE['visits']+1;
    setcookie('visits',$visits,time()+24*3600*365);
    echo "You've visited this website ".$_COOKIE['visits']. ' times before.<br>';
    echo "<a href='?restart=true'>Restart</a><br>";
}
```

The final guess I've come up with right now is that when using a redirect header, the browser does the redirection request **before setting the received cookies**, I'm not sure though. Otherwise, I can't think of anything else that may cause this behavior. Anyone could please comment on this and make it clear?

Comment: I just wanted to say – "I've used browser developer tools and watched each step closely" – God bless you, I wish everyone would do that before posting questions... Now let me see if I can help :)

Comment: This code is actually working as-is for me. When I click "Reset", my cookie is deleted in the redirect and then set again in the successive load of test.php (with a value of "vists=1").

Comment: Make sure $_GET['restart'] value is true.

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser I'm using the latest version of both Chrome and Mozilla. And PHP 7 on Xampp.

Answer (score 1):

In your code it looks like the header is sent and the user is redirected before the cookie is set. You could try [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and echo a dot `echo ".";` directly before the `header(...` line to ensure some communication with the client before they are redirected.

**Edit:** My understanding of what is happening here is that the cookie and redirect headers are being sent simultaneously, but in some server/client combinations the redirect is occurring before the browser has a chance to set the cookie. Pushing some content to the browser along with the headers gives it a chance to process the cookie, but you must obviously enable output buffering in your php.ini or use `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` before and after the header setting and echoing.

Comment: What do you mean "there is no communication with the user?" I get a 302 Found response with a `Set-Cookie: visits=deleted` header during the redirect. Isn't that communication with the user?

Comment: Ah, thank you very much it was really irritating. I wonder how I should have known this? I think it is not even mentioned in the PHP header function documentation? Or maybe I just didn't know where else to look for it.

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser I had observed that too. Just to let you know how much I tried to solve it on my own before posting it ;D

Comment: Interesting. Well, it's working as expected with your current code on my end. The 301 redirect is unsetting the cookie. Then when my browser loads test.php again, it receives a 200 response and a new cookie with a value of 1. Perhaps our different PHP versions or server setups are causing this... In any event, I'm getting all headers sent along with the 301!

Comment: It depends on your webserver, e.g. IIS vs Apache and also whether you have output buffering enabled in php.ini.

Comment: I added some more explanation.

Comment: @user1491032 I thought this would solve my issue but it has not. I tried both of your solutions. Solution 1 (echoing) just doesn't work and also for solution 2, (my output buffering is on and works) I did the buffering/flushing and it doesn't work either. Sorry I took back the answer acceptance tick, I think this is an issue with browsers not handling this properly, actually, I see a "Failed to load response data" in chrome dev tools and I Googled it and it seems that others have had the same issue too and it's kind of a bug. To my astonishment(!) Mozilla has the same bug too. Weird.

Comment: Out of curiosity please could you try `header( "refresh:1;url=test.php" );` instead of location?